Should I buy a home with a foundation repair?
I’m currently under contract to purchase a house, and the seller disclosed that a few years ago, the basement had water leak in through what sounds like 2 cracks in the foundation. Based on an invoice they provided, the cracks were repaired by injecting the cracks with urethane grout and coating with cement/epoxy.
Knowing next to nothing about foundations, I’m just not sure what kind of reaction this warrants and how concerning this is. Is this likely to happen again and is the foundation inherently damaged/compromised? Or with the repair is the chance of it happening again low.
Extra info: House was built in the 90s, in the Midwest, and carpet and drywall were also replaced after leak.

if you do not know what caused it, be worry

It's pretty impossible to give a diagnosis with no information. If you are worried, you need to get a professional foundation inspection done (I did this).

SFAIK urethane is the good stuff,  but it's not going to make the foundation stronger than it originally was (when new)  as for the question  only you can answer that,

Please add location, this is important. Also, describe situation better. It’s next to impossible to seal a basement from too high static water pressure which can be caused from multiple issues ranging from missing downspouts to high water table or missing footer drains, etc.

Foundations settle and crack; they pretty much all do. All foundations are prone to have water around them in the way of falling weather. Drainage will always be an issue, for the possibility of a wet basement.
I would concern myself more with that, the wet basement, not the cracks--those happen all the time. The house was built under the inspection process, and it is highly unlikely the foundation will fail.

This question will get closed as it asks for opinion.  That said, ask the seller for an engineering report.  Look to see if the repair was done as prescribed in the report.
A repair done as per engineering, while having no guarantee, does carry a greater likelihood for a good outcome. Your story said it was done because of a water leak. That does not in itself mean there is a problem with the foundation, only that there was a leak allowing water infiltration. Get as much information as to cause and action taken. Then make your decision.
